# java.lang.runtimeexception error occurred while executing doinbackground() caused by NPE

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse

Whenever I open my app, it crashes and gives me the following logcat errors.
I do not know where I have gone wrong. I wanted to know why my application crashes and how can I fix it.

```
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.example.gravitas2015.MainActivity$jsonhandler.handleResponse(MainActivity.java:284)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.example.gravitas2015.MainActivity$jsonhandler.handleResponse(MainActivity.java:1)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.execute(AndroidHttpClient.java:273)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.example.gravitas2015.MainActivity$request.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:250)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.example.gravitas2015.MainActivity$request.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     ... 4 more
```

Here's my code for doInBackground

```
private class request extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>>{


        AndroidHttpClient client= AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("");
        HttpGet request;

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            if (isOnline())
            {
                try{

                    request = new HttpGet("http://www.com");

                }catch(NullPointerException e ){
                    e.printStackTrace();}
                jsonhandler handler = new jsonhandler();
                try
                {
                    return client.execute(request,handler);
                }catch(ClientProtocolException exception){
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }catch(IOException exception){
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result)
          {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (this.client != null) {
              this.client.close();
            }
          }

    }
private class jsonhandler implements ResponseHandler<List<String>>{
    @Override
    public List<String> handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
            throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        String jsonresponse = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
        int i;
        JSONArray data;
        try {

            data = new JSONArray(jsonresponse);
            for(i=0;i<data.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)data.get(i);
                tid[i]=Integer.parseInt(obj.get("tid").toString());
                name[i]=obj.get("name").toString();
                org[i]=obj.get("organisation").toString();
                desc[i]=obj.getString("description").toString();
                date[i]=obj.get("date").toString();
                time[i]=obj.get("timings").toString();
                loc[i]=obj.get("location").toString();
                fee[i]=obj.get("fee").toString();
                cname1[i]=obj.get("cname1").toString();
                pho1[i]=obj.get("cno1").toString();
                cname2[i]=obj.get("cname2").toString();
                pho2[i]=obj.get("cno2").toString();
                email[i]=obj.get("email").toString();
                team[i]=obj.get("team").toString();


                result.add("EVENT: "+name[i]+"\nDATE: "+date[i]+"\nVENUE: "+loc[i]+"\n");
            }
            k=i;
        }catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }


}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: I did. It was the first fetch statement
tid[i]=Integer.parseInt(obj.get("tid").toString());

Comment: @Karakuri could you tell me how to avoid this specific NPE issue?

Comment: @SteveMathews Something on the line specified is `null`, you need to figure out what. It could either be `tid`, `obj`, or the result of `obj.get("tid")`.

Comment: i think `response` value is `null` as your `http://www.com` is not a valid address to get JSON data.

Comment: That's just for confidentiality. There is an actual link. :D

Comment: Do null check of your response and print what is coming in your data . check the length of your json array. Do null checks where ever you are getting your data. Debug the code and see where the control is going and you will find exactly where it is failing.
You can start using google's own volley library's GsonRequest class and you will be free from the entire hassle of parsing the response etc. GsonRequest will automatically set the setter methods of your result model class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `try` block you say

```
request = new HttpGet("http://gravitas-eshwa.rhcloud.com/eventapi.php");
```

if this fails you `catch NullPointerException` and do

```
jsonhandler handler = new jsonhandler();

try
   {
       return client.execute(request,handler);
   }catch(ClientProtocolException exception){
         exception.printStackTrace();
   }catch(IOException exception){
       exception.printStackTrace();
   }
```

So you simply proceed to

```
return client.execute(request,handler);
```

when you have just caught `request` as `null`, which causes the error. So you have to add something to the first `catch` to react to the null `request`.

Comment: Should I put another catch for NPE then?
But then again, why am I getting a null request? I can see the data and it's fine

Comment: So you checked `request` is not null?

Comment: And NPE is at line 284 where I am fetching the first time
tid[i]=Integer.parseInt(obj.get("tid").toString());

Comment: That is because data is null, because jsonresponse is null, because response is null, because request is null

Comment: I just put another catch statement for NPE now. Didn't solve

Comment: Haha. That's just for displaying here. Have a working link

Comment: I see :p well debug and see that the value you get to request is not null. If there is valid data then I dont know..

Comment: It works now!
For some reason it worked from the third time I tried.
Thanks a lot!
I had worked on Json before and had the catch there. Don't know how I missed it. Another issue now is that I'm not getting all the data.

Comment: Did you try and do a null check on your data. Check the length of your JSONArray data before you start parsing the result data.

Comment: Good to hear. Data problem sounds like another question of there is nothing similar on the site yet :p

Comment: Moreover i will suggest to you that please start using google's own volley library's GsonRequest class and you will be free from the entire hassle of parsing the response etc. GsonRequest will automatically set the setter methods of your result model class.

Comment: @Milez I did just that. Seems perfect. 160. But doesn't fetch the entire data

Comment: @Kaveesh, will do henceforth. Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: Ok, if you need any help using volley do let me know, i have used GsonRequest and other class, i can help you with the code if you want

Comment: Could you just help me out with this? 
I no longer can fetch data. All values show null but the traversal happens 160 times. The data just doesn't store.

Comment: Now it won't even traverse. Wow

Comment: can you show your log so that we can see what exactly is coming in the JSONArray?

Comment: log while opening the application?

Comment: Solved it. Thanks anyways! (y)